# How to setup DNS for CloudFront distribution with ACM for test and production servers pointing to different directory roots?

Tags: ssl, amazon-cloudfront, google-cloud-dns, aws-certificate-manager

I am facing difficulty in serving requests from test.domain.com with the configuration with a combination of AWS Certificate Manager (ACM), AWS EC2 (linux AMI), AWS CloudFront (CF), Google DNS and Apache server.

I have following setup in `public_html` directory:

I have 2 folders in `/var/www/html`

- prod
- test

Objective is to serve requests received from `test.domain.com` using `test` directory and the ones received from `domain.com` using `prod` directory.

The setup is working fine with acme ssl certificates ie., for production (domain.com), we are using acme SSL certificate and DNS is pointing to Elastic IP and working fine.  Even test.domain.com was working
fine with acme ssl setup.

However, I'm trying to switch to ACM.  As it works only with CF and ELB (AWS Elastic Load Balancer), created a CF distribution.

- Created one CloudFront (CF) distribution pointing to AWS EC2 endpoint with Origin path `/test`.
- Redirected `test.domain.com` to CF distribution in Google DNS as the domain is registered with them.

With this setup, `test.domain.com` is also presenting `domain.com` and not the test server as anticipated.

https.conf has correct DocumentRoot for each ServerName.  But, request is not hitting the virtualhost of test server..

whats missing?  pls suggest..

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

1. Add both domain.com and test.domain.com to CloudFront CNAME list.
2. ACM certificate which has common name/SAN as domain.com and *.domain.com (or test.domain.com)
3. In CloudFront cache behavior , whiteist HOST header, this will make sure that when client access domain.com , cloudfront send the same value in host header when contacting origin.

Link:
[Forward host header](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/)

Comment: Thanks @james-dean for the response.  I'm now receiving ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error for test.domain.com.  `AH00569: client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /`

Comment: where do you see this error ? On the origin ? or the client ?

Comment: CloudFront follows RFC and always adds HOST header to the origin

Comment: error is seen in the origin `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and i guess propagated to client.

Comment: after commenting out the directive on port 80 in httpd.conf, the test server is working fine.  the directive on port 80 was conflicting with redirection synthetic record on DNS.  However, the cloudfront distribution url is getting displayed instead of test.domain.com.  Is there any remedy for this ie., if the redirection in DNS is configured to CNAME associated to CF distribution, wouldn't it work?